# Religious film about mind control

Tags: story-identification, movie

People are forced to take an implant or get killed. They're imprisoned (and tortured) for a few weeks they must decide whether take implant or get their head chopped off and other prisoners must watch it, basically a decision between Jesus or implant mind control.

Two friends stole a car and got caught. An ex-policeman tried to free his marked woman, got tortured and agreed to kill a religious leader. He and one of the friend got killed and the remaining friend (storyteller) made wrong decision and took the implant.

Answer (score 5):

This is [Six: The Mark Unleashed](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0344777/), a 2004 "Christian action-drama".

Per [this review](http://io9.com/5692840/the-absolute-greatest-future-dystopia-where-liberals-have-won) on i09

> Jeffrey Dean Morgan plays Tom Freeman, a former cop turned smuggler,
> who hasn't accepted the almost-universal mind-control implant that
> makes you a slave to the Leader and a member of the sexually
> omnivorous Community. In the clip above, he confronts his ex-wife
> Jeseca (Amy Moon), who's gotten the implant and become one of the
> Leader's stooges. She wants Tom to go undercover and infiltrate the
> Christian underground, then kill their leader, Elijah Cohen.

### Trailer

Comment: For the record, this film looks **truly dreadful**. Might I suggest that instead of watching this, you could use the time more wisely. You could take a long bath, learn to cook the perfect omelette or just go to bed slightly earlier...

Comment: For the record, your *synopsis* sounds truly dreadful, and I can only imagine how bad the film must be. :)

Comment: Wow. A world where you have to choose between a specific religion and a mind-control implant is not the, um... *ringing endorsement* they seem to think it is.

Comment: If they made it today, the implant would probably be in a vaccine mandated by Bill Gates.